# Glossaries list - no separating lines

Tags: spacing, glossaries, warnings

I am trying to produce a list of acronyms and definitions in which each entry is at some distance from the previous one. Distance of two lines worked out of the box and I am happy with it, but it is not applied to all entries - some entries start on the next line after the previous one ends. I am also seeing a lot of `underfull hbox` warnings, and I think it might have something to do with the space between entries, but I am not sure how to fix the problem. Is there a way to maintain that two lines space between entries even though the spacing between the words somewhat violates the allowed values?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[xindy,nonumberlist,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\loadglsentries{glossaries}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}
\glossarystyle{long}
\glsaddall
\printglossaries
\end{document}
```

The glossaries file:

```
\newglossaryentry{functesting}
{
name={functional testing},
description={Testing based on an analysis of the specification of the functionality of a        component or system. Performed by black-box testing  techniques.\cite{istqb_glossary}\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{regtesting}
{
name={regression testing},
description={Testing of a previously tested program following modification to ensure  that defects have not been introduced or uncovered in unchanged areas of the software, as a result of the changes made. Performed when the software or its environment is changed.\cite{istqb_glossary}\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{regtesting2}
{
name={regression testing2},
description={Testing of a previously tested program following modification to ensure that defects have not been introduced or uncovered in unchanged areas of the software, as a result of the changes made. Performed when the software or its environment is changed.\cite{istqb_glossary}\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{testauto}
{
name={test automation},
description={See \textit{automated testing}.}
}

\newglossaryentry{sysofsys}
{
name={system of systems},
description={Multiple heterogeneous, distributed systems that are embedded in networks at multiple levels and in multiple interconnected domains, addressing large-scale inter-disciplinary common problems and purposes, usually without a common management structure.\cite{istqb_glossary}\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{sysintegrtest}
{
name={system integration testing},
description={Testing the integration of systems and packages; testing interfaces to external organizations.\cite{istqb_glossary}\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{CR}
{
name={capture/replay},
description={A type of test execution tool where inputs are recorded during manual testing in order to generate automated test scripts that can be executed later (i.e. replayed). These tools are often used to support automated regression testing.Also known as record/playback, capture/playback.\cite{istqb_glossary}\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{RP}
{
name={record/playback},
description={See \textit{capture/replay}.\nopostdesc}
}

\newglossaryentry{CP}
{
name={capture/playback},
description={See \textit{capture/replay}.\nopostdesc}
}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Can you give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), something that we can copy and paste and test?Also, there is no need to say thank you in your post. This might seem strange at first but as you continue to participate in this site, you will get used to it. It is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about)

Comment: Without a MWE it's difficult to answer, but (assuming you're using the `glossaries` package) I suspect the package option `nogroupskip` may be what you're after regarding the spacing between lines. The `underfull hbox` warnings are probably caused by trying to fully justify text in a narrow column, which can happen depending on the glossary style.

Comment: Added a MWE. The nogroupskip made the look of the list consistent, but actually does the opposite of what I want - I do want vertical space between the entries. In the MWE is is not consistent - between some entries there is space, between others there isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the `long` style, which uses a `longtable`. Put this definition in your preamble:

```
\newglossarystyle{mylong}{
\glossarystyle{long}
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2} & ##3\glspostdescription\space ##5\\[10pt]}%
}
```

and use it with `\glossarystyle{mylong}` instead of `\glossarystyle{long}`. 
The above definition of `\glossaryentryfield` is exactly the same as the original of the `long` style, except that the `10pt` space is added after each entry.